# Using jQuery per each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have 4 restaurant timings and I want to see each of their opening hours individually. Right now if I click on opening hours link all 4 divs are affected by that. How can I make sure that if I click on the opening hour link of one restaurant only that restaurant's timings are shown.

So, if you click the open today link in the first section, only the timings of that restaurant should be shown/hide – Dev B 1 min ago   edit
I can not assign individual divs. The divs are being created on its own the php wordpress template

Here is the fiddle so far

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.oh-current-open').each(function(index){
          $(this).click(function() {
            $('.oh-wrapper').animate({
               'height': 'toggle'
          });
       });
     }); 
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpv4o93n/

Comment: Hard to tell without any associated markup, but `$('.oh-wrapper')` being a global selector is a code smell

Comment: Cannot understand your question.

Comment: The jsFiddle is just a bunch of dummy text in columns. Where are the js codes, the `oh-current-open` div, etc?

Comment: can you add a HTML snippet here too so that we can check, your fiddle link represent something else

Comment: you need to add a unique id for each div and then shown it .

Comment: @godie  or use contextual lookups.  Nothing about this right now demands unique ids

Comment: Sorry. I posted the wrong fiddle. Now updated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jpv4o93n/

Comment: So, if you click the open today link in the first section, only the timings of that restaurant should be shown/hide

Comment: I can not assign individual divs. The divs are being created on its own the php wordpress template

Comment: @DevB put that markup in the question please.

Comment: @Taplar yep, but i think the unique ids is the easiest way but is not the best solution.

Comment: Contextual lookups are super easy.  They just demand you have an understanding of the structure of your markup.  And as a developer of the frontend, that's something you should have anyway.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()`. jQuery automatically loops over all the matching elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section is segregated by a travelRow.  You can find the parent travel row that encapsulates all the related elements, and then find the nested oh wrapper that should be animated.

Edit: Also explicitly writing an each is not necessary.  `click` will do an each on the elements as part of its operation.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.oh-current-open').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.travelRow').find('.oh-wrapper').animate({
       'height': 'toggle'
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Taplar ,  `$(this).closest('.travelRow').find('.oh-wrapper')` looks simply equal `$(this).next()`. nope?

Comment: That looks to be true, however that approach is more fragile than the closest find route.  If ever the position of those children change, or is different, the next logic would break.  But yeah, if they wanted to do so, they could use next as well.  @Banzay